# How do I make my app compatible with an android remote control/air mouse?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

So i want to make an app that you can control with a android TV remote and I want to know how to integrate an android remote control and utilize the d pad buttons to select which video they want or image button with a border around to show what they are clicking. This is an app for those android TV/Kodi Box type.

Here is the Design:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2a75.png)

For the border I guess I can change the image using `.setImageResource(R.drawable` if it can detect the remote selection.

Comment: So you didn't find this and go through them all? https://developer.android.com/training/tv/index.html

Comment: Looking at the documents now, but this is mostly for Android TV specifically. Most of the android box run tablet version of android and the call methods for IR remotes and USB remotes may differ,

Comment: Then your question isn't clear. D-pad navigation and focus highlighting is a core part of Android. I referred to the Android TV documentation as it is the closest dealing with a Android device in a tablet/TV configuration. If the third-party device is following HID (usb/bluetooth) then its no different than a keyboard/mouse. If you are asking about custom devices then you are at framework/driver level (e.g. getting the mic to work on a mic/dpad remote).